# Null reference exception from object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nullreferenceexception

I have an application in asp.net core 2.1. I have registered/injected HttpContextAccessor in startup.cs file as like below.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Also i have created an object for the interface IHttpContextAccessor and initiated that object in the constructor of Dependency injection class "GetScopedServicesTools"

```
 public readonly IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;

 public GetScopedServicesTools(IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor)
 {
   HttpContextAccessor = _httpContextAccessor;
 }
```

I have created an object for the DI class "GetScopedServicesTools" but am not sure what value need to be passed to the constructor of that class.

```
private GetScopedServicesTools getScopedServices;
```

Could you please help me what value need to be pass to the constructor of the class "GetScopedServicesTools".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that class with and with the DI container, you should also register `GetScopedServicesTools` with the service provider.

In your `Startup.cs` you can do `services.AddScoped<GetScopedServicesTools>();` and then simply inject it in your controllers or wherever you like.

**Note:**

I would like to point however that the DI mechanism is already providing out-of-the-box what you're trying to achieve with your `GetScopedServicesTools` class. You can simply inject the IHttpContextAccessor wherever you like since you already registered it with the service provider with `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`. What you're doing with your extra class is an anti-pattern and should be avoided.